# Identifying CustomXMLPart dynamically (and keeping the identifier)

Tags: xpath, ms-word, office-interop, domdocument

I am working with a `CustomXMLPart` that I identify by and attribute (@Id).

```
var xPath = "/ns0:customPartParent[1]/ChildNode[@Id='" + id + "']";
contentControl.XMLMapping.SetMapping(xpath, prefix, customPart)
```

When setting the `xPath` of the control to the above, looking at the mapping at runtime, the path stays with the Id - i.e.

`/ns0:customPartParent[1]/ChildNode[@Id='eae2fd04-3a05-42c1-a154-0d7da47cca56']`

But as soon as I provide a FULL path;
`/ns0:customPartParent[1]/ChildNode[@Id='eae2fd04-3a05-42c1-a154-0d7da47cca56']/Value[1]/Item[1]/Fullname[1]`

The @Id, gets replaced with the index of the part attached within the document.

`/ns0:customPartParent[1]/ChildNode[2]/Value[1]/Item[1]/Fullname[1]`

The reason this is an issue is because we have functionality that allows 2 documents to merge, where I copy the `XMLPartNodes` from one document and add it to the 2nd document's node(s) - if these are indexed, they will obviously look at the wrong items within the customXMLPart.

I would like to try force the @Id to stay so that when I move this part to another document, the part will be identified with the same @id and not by index?

Any ideas?

UPDATE: This only happens once you add Repeating content controls, as soon as I add my repating controls, all Id's disappear and reverts to index numbers.

Value of the content control before repeating item added: 
`/ns0:customPartParent[1]/ChildNode[@Id='1cae3c3f-c847-4a7c-91dc-5625a2228a11']/Value[1]/Item[1]/Fullname[1]`

Value of the content control after repeating item added: 
`/ns0:customPartParent[1]/ChildNode[2]/Value[1]/Item[1]/Fullname[1]`

Comment: Is this a binding to a repeating content control? Or is the repeating content control just added somewhere else to the document?

Comment: The repeating control gets added to these controls. So for example,I create a table with two cells, one row. Add a content control to cell 1 and 2 (ID mappings are perfect) I then add a repeating control to that same first row (as the xml part has multiple items), once that is added, the ID's are removed and all get indexed. You could reproduce this using that exact same scenario (just make sure your xml part has more than one item, so that the repeating control actually does its job :))

Comment: If I understood correctly, the binding is **within** a repeating content control (because you added that repeating content control to that very same table row). I don't see how the repeating content control could handle the binding other than by using the index, therefore I think the behavior you see is very likely by design.

Comment: So far that's also all I've found, seems it my be by design, it's just weird that functionality is based on control type. (It's just an xpath).